# How do I change the fontstyle to bold on a font I already created as regular

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I am allowing the use of themes in  my application. So I create a font based on the user's choice of themes. However, I need to change the fontstyle from regular to bold, but I don't want to have to recreate the font.

I am doing it this way, because not all users will have the font installed on their machine. So I am embedding the font into the application.

For example: I may have a textbox assigned the font like this:

```
txtbox.font = theme_font
```

Is there a way to simply change the style to bold?

```
txtbox.font = theme_font.fontstyle.bold ' <-- this doesn't work
```

I call the font creation subroutine like this:

```
Public Shared theme_font = BerlinSans.GetInstance(theme_font_size, FontStyle.Regular)
```

And this is the subroutine being called:

```
Module BerlinSans

   'PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION TO HOLD THE DYNAMIC FONT
    Private _pfc As PrivateFontCollection = Nothing

  Public ReadOnly Property GetInstance(ByVal Size As Single, ByVal style As FontStyle) As Font

        Get
            'IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME GETTING AN INSTANCE
            'LOAD THE FONT FROM RESOURCES
            If _pfc Is Nothing Then LoadFont()

            'RETURN A NEW FONT OBJECT BASED ON THE SIZE AND STYLE PASSED IN
            Return New Font(_pfc.Families(0), Size, style)

        End Get

  End Property

  Private Sub LoadFont()

        Try
            'INIT THE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection

            'LOAD MEMORY POINTER FOR FONT RESOURCE
            Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.BRLNSR.Length)

            'COPY THE DATA TO THE MEMORY LOCATION
            Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.BRLNSR, 0, fontMemPointer, My.Resources.BRLNSR.Length)

            'LOAD THE MEMORY FONT INTO THE PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, My.Resources.BRLNSR.Length)

            'FREE UNSAFE MEMORY
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontMemPointer)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'ERROR LOADING FONT. HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
        End Try

    End Sub


End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**`Font(Font, FontStyle)` constructor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdte89fc(v=vs.110).aspx). Just pass it the old font and the new style you want to use and it'll copy the properties from the old font into the new one for you (apart from the style, of course).

```
txtbox.Font = New Font(theme_font, FontStyle.Bold)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it says:  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:

Comment: @user2721815 : There must be more information than that? Because that is not enough for me to tell what the problem is. What exactly did you write in your code? Or did you just copy-paste mine?

Comment: @user2721815 : I think I see where the problem could be. I'm not certain, but it is a possibility: Try declaring `theme_font` with a specific type rather than inferring it. It could be that the compiler isn't fully aware of what type it is, thus it is unsure which overload to pick. Try specifying that the variable is a `Font` and see if that works: `Public Shared theme_font As Font = BerlinSans.GetInstance(theme_font_size, FontStyle.Regular)`

Comment: @user2721815 : Any luck with this? If you're still having problems please send me (a) screenshot(s) with as much information as possible related to the error, and I'll see if that helps me identify what causes it.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, your suggestion of declaring the theme font as a type worked. So the new line looks like: Public Shared theme_font As Font = Arial.GetInstance(theme_font_size, FontStyle.Regular). Now I can use .Font = New Font(theme_font, FontStyle.Bold) without getting an error.

Comment: @user2721815 : Glad I could help! :)